# Where is this verse found in Vishnu Purana?

Tags: puranas, vishnu-purana

Kindly provide chapter and verse number for the Shloka. Is this shloka found somewhere else other than Vishnu Purana?

> त्रयस्त्रिंशत्सहस्त्रनी त्रयस्त्रिंश्च्चतानी च। त्रयस्त्रिंशत्त्था देवा पिबंती क्षणदाकरम।।

> trayastriṁśatsahastranī trayastriṁśccatānī ca। trayastriṁśattthā dēvā pibaṁtī kṣaṇadākarama।।

Comment: @Proxy you have changed the question... OP wants that verse somewhere else (not in Vishnu Purana)...

Comment: I guess OP is asking for both the things. @tezz

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is in Vishnu purana book 2, chapter 12, 7th shloka . https://archive.org/details/vishnupuranasanskritenglishocr/page/n229/mode/2up  Here you can find both sanskrit text along with english translation

Answer (score 3):

It is verse 2.12.7 according to the Vishnu purana edition [here](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/corpustei/transformations/html/sa_viSNupurANa.htm).

Comment: Thank you for the reference but how does the translation of Thirty three thousand thirty three hundred thirty three provided into numerals?

Comment: @Shiva The translator Wilson just adds these numbers  to get 36333